# npm module or software which checks and tells what methods we have used for node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, reactjs, npm

I am working on a JS application which has a lot of NPM modules written in NodeJS and ReactJS. Since NodeJS is a big framework i'm not sure which NodeJS methods are used. Are there any NPM modules or software which checks and tells what methods we have used in our NodeJS code?

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. - [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @MikeC I searched but not able to find anything :(

Comment: It's still off-topic. Not to mention, what do you mean "what methods we have used in node js code"? Do you mean every single function that you call in the entire program, including ones you've created yourself? It's unlikely that such a tool exists. You could make one by parsing all of your files into an AST and checking every function call but that's a rather big project.

Comment: @MikeC only the inbuilt methods from node js framework